# Need a help in MySQL Syncronization

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, sqlyog

For one of my project that I'm current working, I need to sync local mysql databas with the server db. There will be 2 machines which connect to the same db in the server. I use SQL Yog Software for mysql synchronization with the online db. Its currently working perfectly. Currently I have a static IP but when I put the app to the client's machine, I'm not sure he has a static IP. But I want to know do I have to have a static IP for mysql sync with the server db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a static IP. You can create a user (using the User manager) with the host as the client system name as well.

For example:  [image]

Comment: Wont it be an issue when the IP has changed. Because the webserver db has pointed to that particular machine IP

Comment: What is the software that you're using here?

Comment: ok, hope this must be a latest version, I have version 7.15, btw, thank mate, I'll try it

Comment: Yes the latest version 9.33 (i'm in dev for SQLyog btw) and It works here. Yup! let me know!